# ArrayOutOfBound exception while using Vector in java

Tags: java, vector

I am programming a neural network and I have the following problem: 
I have 2 classes: Perceptron and NeuralNetwork, in NeuralNetwork I wrote this C'tor:

```
    //First Layer initialization
    for (int i=0; i<100;i++) {
        Perceptron p = new Perceptron(true);
        Information temp = new Information(1,null);
        p.v.addElement(temp);
    //  p.v.elementAt(i).setWeight(1);
        layer1.addElement(p);
    }

    //Second Layer initialization
    for (int i=0;i<70;i++) {
        Perceptron p = new Perceptron(false);
        for (int j=0; j<100;j++) {
            double t = 0;
            while ((t = r.nextDouble()) == 0);
            Information tmp=new Information(t, layer1.elementAt(j));
            p.v.addElement(tmp);
        }
        layer2.addElement(p);
    }

    //Third Layer initialization
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        Perceptron p = new Perceptron(false);
        for (int j=0;j<70;j++) {
            double t = 0;
            while ((t = r.nextDouble()) == 0);
            Information tmp=new Information(t, layer2.elementAt(j));
            p.v.addElement(tmp);
        }
        layer3.addElement(p);
    }
```

and in Perceptron the C'tor is:

```
public Perceptron(boolean inpt)
{
    isInput=inpt;

}
```

I am trying to run this function (in NeuralNetwork):

```
public double[] exituteNet(int [][]in)
{   

    //Translate m*n matrix to m*n array 
    double [] inputArr=new double[in.length*in[0].length];
    for(int i=0,count=0;i<in.length;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<in[0].length;j++)
        {
            inputArr[count]=in[i][j];
            count++;
        }

    for(int i=0;i<layer1.size();i++)
    {
        layer1.elementAt(i).input.setElementAt(inputArr[i], 0);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<layer2.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<layer1.size();j++)
            layer2.elementAt(i).input.setElementAt(layer1.elementAt(j).output(), j);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<layer3.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<layer2.size();j++)
            layer3.elementAt(i).input.setElementAt(layer2.elementAt(j).output(), j);
    }

    double[]res= new double[layer3.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<res.length;i++)
        res[i]=layer3.elementAt(i).output();
    return res;
}
```

and I get tons of `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`s, starting from this line:

```
        layer1.elementAt(i).input.setElementAt(inputArr[i], 0);
```

I also tried to change NeuralNetwork initialization (first layer function) to :

```
    for (int i=0; i<100;i++) {
        Perceptron p = new Perceptron(true);
        p.v.elementAt(i).setWeight(1);
        layer1.addElement(p);
    }
```

and I got `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` here as well.

*input,v are vectors in Perceptron class

I have no idea what to do, and I will be glad for help

Comment: inputArr is not a vector, it seems to me. basically, you are trying to get an element from an invalid (less then 0, or higher than the nr of elements) index somewhere. the stacktrace tells you which line it happens, debug and check which specific element

Comment: I think the problem may be here: `for(int j=0;j<in[0].length;j++)`